# HTML: table row/table cell to close or not to close?

Tags: html, tags

I want your opinion on this question.
Is it that necessarily to close the `<tr>` and `<td>` tags?
Most web editor/design softwares prefer having these tags closed, I personally think it's more ergonomic to leave the tags open.
You can easily distinct the start and the end of a row if you properly write your code.

```
<table>
<tr><td class="login_cell">Login:
    <td><input type="text" name="user_login" class="input" autocomplete="off">
<tr><td class="login_cell">Password:
    <td><input type="password" name="user_pass" class="input">
<tr><td><a href="">Forgot password?</a>
        <input type="hidden" name="log" value="ok">
    <td><input type="submit" name="btn_login" class="btn" value="Log in">
</table>
```

Comment: What doctype are you using?

Comment: So HTML5. Yes, you need to close those tags for your HTML to validate. Most browsers will probably render it correctly anyway but why don't close them?

Comment: I know, so closing them seems useless if browsers show them anyway.

Comment: Wouldn't it look better if you close it? I personally close as it leaves a "Clean" code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always close HTML tags in HTML5! Whether it's a short tag (e.g., `<img src="image.png alt="image" />`) or a regular tag. (e.g., `<div id="myDiv">Content</div>`)

Comment: As per all container tags (p, li, td...) they definitely should be closed, even though most browsers can handle them unclosed. As per so called void elements (meta, img, br, etc.) more and more voices say they should not be closed. Myself, I have spent so many years with XHTML apps, I'm now very uncomfortable seeing *any* tag not closed. http://www.impressivewebs.com/html5-syntax-style/  There was also an article on sitepoint.com but I cannot find it now.

Answer (score 2):

**Pros:**

- less characters --> page loads faster
- (the thing you said, which I don't think is a good reason)

**Cons:**

- Hard to maintain
- No valid XHTML
- Might mess up CSS/JS
- Not always allowed
- Might not be rendered correctly by all browsers (Yeah, I'm talking to you, IE!)
- Bad, bad style...

Summa summarum, I'd close the tags...

Answer (score 1):

The rules are:

XHTML: You have to close all tags.

HTML: You only need to close the table tag.

My advice would be to always close the tags in a table. That makes it easier to keep track of everything, and a lot easier if you would choose to use XHTML instead of HTML.